# Does erase() in C++'s STL actually delete the element?

Tags: c++, stl

For the following code:

```
 list<int> P;
int i,n,x;
cin>>n>>x;
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    P.push_back(i+1);
list<int>::iterator t2,t1=P.begin();
advance(t1,x-1);
t2=t1;
t1++;
P.erase(t1);
t2++;
cout<<*t2<<" ";
cout<<*(P.end())<<endl;
```

when the input I give is: **5 3**,

the ouput comes out to be **5 4**.

I am actually deleting the element 4 from the list. But it is going to the end of list. How do I avoid this? I want to completely remove 4 from the list so that the last element in the list is 5.

Comment: `*(P.end())` is undefined behavior, since `std::vector::end` is, by the very definition, **past** the end of the `std::vector`.

Comment: So how do I check in O(1) that 5 is the last element in the list or not? And this function is std::list::end. And I quite didn't get your point, I'm a beginner.

Comment: std::list::back() gets the last element.  See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/back

Comment: Undefined behavior means anything can happen. Although the language does not try to stop you, you are not permitted to dereference P.end().

Comment: @Tanay Sorry, didn't read the sample fully, and assumed you were using `std::vector`. Nevertheless - iterator functionality is the same across all containers - dereferencing `end ()` is undefined behavior (i.e. any output is valid). To access the last element (assuming non-empty list) one can use [`std::list::back`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/back).

Comment: Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 6):

> Does erase() in C++'s STL actually delete the element?

Yes. `erase` does *destroy* the element.

> But it is going to the end of list.
>
> ```
> *(P.end())
> ```

`end` returns past the end iterator. Dereferencing it has undefined behaviour. You can use `back` to get the last element.

Answer (score 0):

When you call the `erase()` it deletes the element in the internal storage.

A test you can perform to test it is this:

```
int main()
{
    vector<int> x = {3, 4, 5, 6};
    int * temp  = &x[1];
    cout<<*temp<<endl;
    x.erase(x.begin() + 1);
    cout<<*temp<<endl;

}
```

The output shows:

```
4
5
```

Which shows the the erase removes the element and shifts all the elements in its spot.

Hope this helps.